# Finding or creating a mehod with the opposite of the handleMessage method behavior which it is triggered when a message is sent

Tags: omnet++

The `handleMessage()` function is triggered when a message is received.
How to have a function when a message is sent, it is triggered?
Thanks

Comment: Let's consider that module A has sent a message towards module B. After some time module B will receive this message and `handleMessage()` will be called in module B. Could you explain for that situation in which module *function when a message is send* should be triggered?

Comment: Dear @JerzyD. in response to your question ("Could you explain for that situation in which module function when a message is send should be triggered"), module A.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your simple module define a method that will be triggered, for example:

```
void MyModule::handleSending() {
    // do something
}
```

Then in the **every** place of your module where a message is sending add this method, for example:

```
...
send(packet, "out");
handleSending();
...
```